# USB Stick Drive Losing Format

Tags: usb-flash-drive, format, chkdsk

I have just purchased a new 64GB USB stick drive.  It came formatted as FAT32, and I reformatted with Windows 10 as exFAT.  It keeps losing the format, though.  The process which I've followed several times is this:

1. Format (quick or otherwise) as exFAT with default allocation size.
2. Copy some files
3. Safely eject, then reinsert and verify files can be accessed; performed on both Win 10 and Ubuntu
4. Copy all my other files - about 6 GB total
5. Safely eject and insert a few times - no problem
6. Reinsert drive and suddenly Windows says I need to format the disk.  Ubuntu gives a different error, but same idea.

I have wasted hours reformatting and copying multiple times but all to the same end.  I tried to run chkdsk on it, and chkdsk tells me:

> The type of the file system is exFAT.
>   Volume Serial Number is 90DA-DB42
>   Both copies of the boot information for this volume are corrupt.
>   Chkdsk cannot continue.
>   An error occurred while examining the boot region.

Can anyone explain what looks like is going on here?

Comment: As stated in the post: "...Windows says I need to format the disk"

Comment: If you let Windows format the disk, what filesystem does it end up with? Is it then reliable?

Comment: I'm formatting as exFAT and getting the issues outlined in the post.  Needless to say, the results are *not* reliable.

Comment: If it still doesn't work using a different USB port on the computer then it looks like the drive is faulty.

Comment: Yes, this is my supposition, but I'd like to be able to perform more thorough analysis in support of that hypothesis.  What would cause corruption of both copies of the boot record, I wonder?

Comment: You could search for "check usb drive is good quality". I have not tried any of the utilities found through that. I suppose faulty RAM could cause the problem, although I would have thought that other problems would surface sooner. Does the same problem happen if you repeat the procedure on an Ubuntu machine - presumably a physically different PC? Can use format the drive with NTFS instead? Is the drive from a reputable manufacturer?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, please place at least the first part of your comment in an answer, as that looks like it'll help me get the closest I can to confirmation of the issue.

Comment: If it helps you determine where (and hopefully what) the problem is, please feel free to post it and your findings as an answer, then accept it (I think there is some time delay before you can accept it). You'll get a couple of reputation points: I don't need them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two programs useful to help identify the issue: [RMPrepUSB](http://www.rmprepusb.com/home) and [ChkFlsh](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/download/did/75/) useful.

Thanks Andrew Morton!

Comment: You're welcome. Can you tell us what the issue turned out to be? Otherwise it could end up as a situation like [Wisdom of the Ancients](https://xkcd.com/979/).

Comment: Hahahahaha been there, sir, been there.  I was unable to identify specifically why the boot record was being corrupted, but there was a very large amount of bad sectors.  Just cheap shoddy manufacturing.  It was enough information to condemn the drive to the trash.